# How many ways are there in total to feed a command with input?

Tags: command-line, input

First thing I noticed about Linux was the different ways of feeding 
data into a command, I know a few but I do not know how many there 
are in total.

the ways I know so far:

piping:

```
echo -e "zorro\nwurst\nlahmacun\nsozialhilfe" | sort
```

from keyboard with End of file signal:

```
sort
>gurken
>zucker
>braunkohle
```

from file:

```
sort foo
```

HERE string (actually called HERE document):

```
sort << HERE
>wasserkopf
>elternzeit
>schuldeingeständnis
>währungsreform
>alabasterhaut
HERE
```

Is this all or are there more ways to do it, why are there different ways at all, are some ways redundant?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least the following:

1. Command options: `foo --bar`
2. Standard input: `foo | bar` or `bar < foo`
3. File(s): `foo *.*` (or by opening file(s) via code in `foo`) †
4. Environment export: `export foo=bar; baz`
5. Environment (without export): `foo=bar baz` or `env foo=bar baz`
6. HERE doc: `foo << EOF 
   bar 
   EOF`
7. HERE string: `foo <<< bar`
8. Signals `kill -SIGUSR1 $procid`
9. A whole variety of [inter-process communications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), such as sockets, TCP, memory-mapped files

† yes, I realize stdin is a file (or file-like). And that passing in files like this is really the same as passing in options

Comment: You might add `foo < bar` as an additional variant (file via stdin)

Answer (score 14):

To begin with, `sort << HERE` and so on is not a here-string. That's a here-document. The here-string uses the `<<<` operator. That's in bash (and some other shells).

In general, there are two ways. One is through standard input (and redirections), and the other one is through parameters.

1. Standard input and its redirections

   This is the stream that is by default connected to the terminal, in which a command executes and is associated with fd (file descriptor) 1. It's fed whatever is typed to the terminal. Though it (the input) can be redirected as in using the pipe `|` or using the here-documents or here-strings. Then the input doesn't come from the terminal, but is attached to the standard output of the command preceding the pipe. Different shells have different redirections, so for this category you should check the shell documentation. Look for *input redirections.*
2. Parameters

   This is what in your example is `sort foo`. Calling a program or a function you pass it one or more parameters. A local file is just one possibility. The parameter might contain a URL or whatever. The options here are endless.

To sum up, there are two general ways:

- the first one abstracts from the application's inner logic and manipulates the standard input on the OS/shell level,
- while the second one involves the application's innards, and it's them that offer limitless possibilities, basing on the call parameters as an interface.

For both ways the answer is there are no limits. Though the actual limits come with the OS/shell and the application itself.